# I am not able to fetch response from server in ReactJS (SOAP). I tried using both fetch and XMLHttpRequest

Tags: reactjs, soap, xmlhttprequest, fetch, fedex

I am trying to integrate fedex api's into ReactJS or rather NextJS Application. So far I have tried using fetch and XMLHttpRequest. Below is the code that I tried using XHR:

```
let XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
        XHR.open('POST', 'https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services', true);
        let soapData = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v8="http://fedex.com/ws/vacs/v8">' +
        '<soapenv:Header/>' +
        '<soapenv:Body>' +
          '<v8:ServiceAvailabilityRequest>' +
            '<v8:WebAuthenticationDetail>' +
              '<v8:ParentCredential>' +
                '<v8:Key>XXXXX</v8:Key>' +
                '<v8:Password> XXXX</v8:Password>' +
              '</v8:ParentCredential>' +
              '<v8:UserCredential>' +
                '<v8:Key> XXXXX</v8:Key>' +
                '<v8:Password> XXXXX</v8:Password>' +
              '</v8:UserCredential>' +
            '</v8:WebAuthenticationDetail>' +
            '<v8:ClientDetail>' +
              '<v8:AccountNumber> XXXX </v8:AccountNumber>' +
              '<v8:MeterNumber> XXXXX</v8:MeterNumber>' +
              '<v8:Localization>' +
                '<v8:LanguageCode>EN</v8:LanguageCode>' +
                '<v8:LocaleCode>US</v8:LocaleCode>' +
              '</v8:Localization>' +
            '</v8:ClientDetail>' +
            '<v8:TransactionDetail>' +
              '<v8:CustomerTransactionId>Services Avaibility</v8:CustomerTransactionId>' +
            '</v8:TransactionDetail>' +
              '<v8:Version>' +
                '<v8:ServiceId>vacs</v8:ServiceId>' +
                '<v8:Major>8</v8:Major>' +
                '<v8:Intermediate>0</v8:Intermediate>' +
                '<v8:Minor>0</v8:Minor>' +
              '</v8:Version>' +
              '<v8:Origin>' +
                '<v8:PostalCode>400061</v8:PostalCode>' +
                '<v8:CountryCode>IN</v8:CountryCode>' +
              '</v8:Origin>' +
              '<v8:Destination>' +
                '<v8:PostalCode>560055</v8:PostalCode>' +
                '<v8:CountryCode>IN</v8:CountryCode>' +
              '</v8:Destination>' +
              '<v8:ShipDate>2019-05-21</v8:ShipDate>' + 
              '<v8:CarrierCode>FDXE</v8:CarrierCode>' +
            '</v8:ServiceAvailabilityRequest>' +
          '</soapenv:Body>' +
        '</soapenv:Envelope>';

      XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
      XHR.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-origin', '*')
      XHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(XHR.readyState == 4) {
          if(XHR.status == 200) {
            console.log(soapData)
          }
        }
      }


      XHR.send(soapData)
```

I get different HTTP error for e.g. (405, 501, 400). Along with this I am getting CORS error which is as follows:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://wsbeta.fedex.com/web-services' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.**

For CORS I have tried mode cors in fetch request and with XHR I have set header to Access-Control-Allow-Origin as *, but I am still getting the same error.

I have also installed the extension from chrome web store which has solved the CORS problem yesterday but today I am again facing the same. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall the extension already.

I have also tried adding

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, if your server doesn't allow CORS then it doesn't matter what you put in your client. Your server must allow e.g localhost:3000 so that you can do your request.

Comment: Yes, I know that any idea about the http response code that I am getting.

Comment: Hi, yes. https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html So 405 method not allowed, normally applies if you are doing a call the api does not support. 400 I guess is because you get CORS blocked. 501 is not implemented. Anyways if you are CORS blocked you need to solve that pre flight first